# Is it possible to programmatically combine the content of certain HTML tags using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, pdf, beautifulsoup, epub

I am using a program called Calibre to convert a PDF file to a EPUB file, but the results are quite messy and unreadable. In earnest, a EPUB file is just a collection of HTML files, and the result of the conversion is messy because Calibre interprets each line of the PDF file as a

element, which creates lots of ugly line breaks in the EPUB file.

Since the EPUB is really a collection of HTML files, it can be parsed using Beautiful Soup. However, the program that I wrote to look for  elements with the "calibre1" class (a normal paragraph) and combine those into single  elements (so there are no ugly line breaks) does not work and I cannot figure why.

Can Beautiful Soup handle what I am trying to do?

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = "C:\\Users\\Eunice\\Desktop\\eBook"

for pathname, directorynames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    # Get all HTML files in the target directory
    for file_name in filenames:
        # Open each HTML file, which is encoded using the "Latin1" encoding scheme
        with open(pathname + "\\" + file_name, 'r', encoding="Latin1") as file:
            # Create a list, which we will write our new HTML tags to later
            html_elem_list: list = []
            # Create a BS4 object
            soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
            # Create a list of all BS4 elements, which we will traverse in the proceeding loop
            html_elements = [x for x in soup.find_all()]

            for html_element in html_elements:
                try:
                    # Find the element with a class called "calibre1," which is how Calibre designates normal body text in a book
                    if html_element.attrs['class'][0] in 'calibre1':
                        # Combine the next element with the previous element if both elements are part of the same body text
                        if html_elem_list[-1].attrs['class'][0] in 'calibre1':
                            # Remove nonbreaking spaces from this element before adding it to our list of elements
                            html_elem_list[-1].string = html_elem_list[-1].text.replace(
                                '\n', '&nbsp;') + html_element.text
                    # This element must not be of the "calibre1" class, so add it to the list of elements without combining it with the previous element
                    else:
                        html_elem_list.append(html_element)
                # This element must not have any class, so add it to the list of elements without combining it with the previous element
                except KeyError:
                    html_elem_list.append(html_element)

            # Create a string literal, which we will eventually write to our resultant file
            str_htmlfile = ''
            # For each element in the list of HTML elements, append the string representation of that element (which will be a line of HTML code) to the string literal
            for elem in html_elem_list:
                    str_htmlfile = str_htmlfile + str(elem)
        # Create a new file with a distinct variation of the name of the original file, then write the resultant HTML code to that file
        with open(pathname + "\\" + '_modified_' + file_name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(str_htmlfile.encode('Latin1'))
```

Here is an input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Latin1'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">

<body class="calibre">
<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was</p>
<p class="calibre1">a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman</p>
<p class="calibre1">who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the</p>
<p class="calibre1">counterman to approach to store her slip.</p>
<p class="calibre1">642</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is what I expect to happen:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Latin1'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">

<body class="calibre">
<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the counterman to approach to store her slip.642</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is the actual output:

```
<html lang="" xml:lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body class="calibre">
<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was</p>
<p class="calibre1">a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman</p>
<p class="calibre1">who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the</p>
<p class="calibre1">counterman to approach to store her slip.</p>
<p class="calibre1">642</p>
</body></html><body class="calibre">
<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was</p>
<p class="calibre1">a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman</p>
<p class="calibre1">who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the</p>
<p class="calibre1">counterman to approach to store her slip.</p>
<p class="calibre1">642</p>
</body><p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
```

Comment: Can you provide some html and expected output?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, QHarr. I added the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Excuse the redundancy, I meant to tag you, @QHarr.

Comment: Can we assume, there are allways only `class="calibre5"` and `class="calibre1"`

Comment: Indeed, there will always be a `class="calibre1"`, but not a `class="calibre5"`. Sometimes, there will not be a `class="calibre5"`, but rather a `class="calibreX"`, where X could equal 2-4.

Comment: I'd like to thank both @Stovefl and Martin for their helpful responses. I awarded points to both answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: programmatically combine the content of certain HTML tags

This example uses `lxml` to parse the XHTML file and build an new XHTML tree.

```
import io, os
from lxml import etree

XHTML = b"""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Latin1'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<body class="calibre">
<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was</p>
<p class="calibre1">a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman</p>
<p class="calibre1">who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the</p>
<p class="calibre1">counterman to approach to store her slip.</p>
<p class="calibre1">642</p>
</body></html>"""

class Calibre2EPUB(etree.iterparse):
    def __init__(self, fh):
        """
        Initialize 'iterparse' to only generate 'start' and 'end' events
        :param fh: File Handle from the XHTML File to parse
        """
        super().__init__(fh, events=('start', 'end'))
        self.parse()

    def element(self, elem, parent=None):
        """
        Copy 'elem' with attributes and text to new Element
        :param elem: Source Element
        :param parent: Parent of the new Element
        :return: New Element
        """
        if parent is None:
            e  = etree.Element(elem.tag, nsmap={None: etree.QName(elem).namespace})
        else:
            e = etree.SubElement(parent, elem.tag)

        [e.set(key, elem.attrib[key]) for key in elem.attrib]

        if elem.text:
            e.text = elem.text

        return e

    def parse(self):
        """
        Parse all Elements, copy Elements 1:1 except <p class:'calibre1' Element
        Aggregate all <p class:'calibre1' text to one Element
        :return: None
        """
        self.calibre1 = None

        for event, elem in self:
            if event == 'start':
                if elem.tag.endswith('html'):
                    self._xhtml = self.element(elem)

                elif elem.tag.endswith('body'):
                    self.body = self.element(elem, parent=self._xhtml)

            if event == 'end':
                if elem.tag.endswith('p'):
                    _class = elem.attrib['class']
                    if not _class == 'calibre1':
                        p = self.element(elem, parent=self.body)
                    else:
                        if self.calibre1 is None:
                            self.calibre1 = self.element(elem, parent=self.body)
                        else:
                            self.calibre1.text += ' ' + elem.text

    @property
    def xhtml(self):
        """
        :return: The new Element Tree XHTML
        """
        return etree.tostring(self._xhtml, xml_declaration=True, encoding='Latin1', pretty_print=True)
```

> **Usage**_

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # with open(os.path.join(pathname, file_name), 'rb', encoding="Latin1") as in_file:
    with io.BytesIO(XHTML) as in_file:
        print(Calibre2EPUB(in_file).xhtml.decode())

    #with open(os.path.join(pathname, '_modified_' + file_name), 'wb') as out_file:
    #    out_file.write(Calibre2EPUB(xml_file).xhtml)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='Latin1'?>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
> <body class="calibre">
> <p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler</p>
> <p class="calibre1">In the California registry, ... (omitted for brevity)to store her slip. 642</p>
> </body></html>
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using BeautifulSoup by using `extract()` to remove the unwanted `<p>` elements and then use `new_tag()` to create a new `<p>` tag containing the text from all of the removed elements. For example:

```
html = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Latin1'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">

<body class="calibre">
<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler1</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was</p>
<p class="calibre1">a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman</p>
<p class="calibre1">who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the</p>
<p class="calibre1">counterman to approach to store her slip.</p>
<p class="calibre1">642</p>

<p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">Note for Tyler2</p>
<p class="calibre1">In the California registry, there was</p>
<p class="calibre1">a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman</p>
<p class="calibre1">who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the</p>
<p class="calibre1">counterman to approach to store her slip.</p>
<p class="calibre1">642</p>

</body></html>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for level, group in groupby(soup.find_all("p", class_=re.compile(r"calibre\d")), lambda x: x["class"][0]):
    if level == "calibre1":
        calibre1 = list(group)
        p_new = soup.new_tag('p', attrs={"class" : "calibre1"})
        p_new.string = ' '.join(p.get_text(strip=True) for p in calibre1)
        calibre1[0].insert_before(p_new)

        for p in calibre1:
            p.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Would give you HTML as:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Latin1'?>
<html lang="" xml:lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <body class="calibre">
  <p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">
   Note for Tyler1
  </p>
  <p class="calibre1">
   In the California registry, there was a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the counterman to approach to store her slip. 642
  </p>
  <p class="calibre5" id="calibre_pb_62">
   Note for Tyler2
  </p>
  <p class="calibre1">
   In the California registry, there was a calm breeze blowing through the room. A woman who must have just walked in quietly beckoned for the counterman to approach to store her slip. 642
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

It works by finding runs of `calibre1` tags. For each run, it first combines the text from all of them and inserts a new tag before the first one. It then removes all of the old tags.

The logic might need to be modified for more complex scenarios in your EPUB file but this should help get you started.